# About fractional modulus

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading paper and it had some expression modulo $1$, and modulo $\frac12$. Could someone explain me what this $2$ things even mean? I'm confused mainly by the fact of divisibility over rationals. Is it maybe something more related to congruence as a property of groups?

Answer (score 1):

Without any more context I can't be certain, but I don't see any reason it should be different from regular modulus: 
$$x\equiv y \pmod a \iff \exists n\in \Bbb Z: n(x-y) = a$$